# Counting records by user

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL (AIX) and I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to find out how many orders are keyed in by each user:

```
so-order-no   user-id
1234          John
2345          John
4567          Bill
7890          Bill
3455          Bill
2144          Fred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple COUNT and GROUP BY

```
SELECT user-id, count(so-order-no) AS TotalOrders
FROM ordertable
GROUP BY user-id
```

Note, I don't know the table name so I have called generically `ordertable`. Substitute with your real table name

[GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
[COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: I've been scratching my head on this one for a few hours myself. This returned exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!